# Why URL module ignores characters after # in node.js

Tags: node.js, url

I am using url module, which basically splits a web address into readable part.

```
var data = url.parse(request.url).pathname
```

the output of request.url is C:\AppFolder\dropbox\videos\myVideo8#.MP4. After its get parsed, I dont understand why its not returing the value with "#.MP4"

Answer (score 0):

> I dont understand why its not returing the value with "#.MP4"

Because `#.MP4` is the *fragment* and not the *path* component of the URL. (You can read up on URL syntax f.e. on WikiPedia, if you are not sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax)

You want to look at `hash`, not `pathname` https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_hash